# Cast List<List<String>> to List<String>

Tags: java, compilation, java-17

How this code is working in Java (I tested it with java 17)?

```
import java.util.List;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> test = (List<String>) getLists();
        System.out.print(test);

    }

    private static Object getLists() {
        return List.of(List.of("123", "456"));
    }
}
```

the output is:

```
[[123, 456]]
```

shouldn't the types mismatch and have an exception of some sort ?

Comment: The generics are only avalable at compile time. There is no type check at runtime

Comment: Try to do something with an element as a string, for example `test.get(0).toLowerCase()`, and you will see the expected exception. `System.out.print(test);` uses the overload for an `Object`, so...

Comment: Did you notice the unchecked conversion warning during compilation at the point where you cast to `List<String>`?  That was the type mismatch error you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now try adding at the end of your `main` method:

```
String x = test.get(0);
```

and watch as you get a `ClassCastException`. Which is weird, as that line.. has zero casts on it.

Generics are a figment of the compiler's imagination. The runtime has no idea. Hence, at runtime, that's just:

```
List list = (List) getlists();
```

which is, of course, fine. The reference returned by the `getLists()` method is pointing at an object of type `List`. Not `List<String>` or even `List<List<String>>` - at runtime **generics do not exist at all**.

Hence, the compiler simulates it all. Which means this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Hi!");
String y = list.get(0);
```

Is translated to:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("Hi!");
String y = (String) list.get(0);
```

and this explains why your code snippet seems to work (though, you do get that warning: That's the compiler saying: Um, that whole generics stuff? I'm the only one that does that, and with these casts I cannot do my job so, well, if you say so, I guess I shall continue assuming that you are right. If you're wrong, weird things are going to happen. Like ClassCastException occurs on lines with zero casts in them!)

`toString()` of List doesn't use its own generics to do its job, hence, you never run into one of those invisible casts that will asplode once you get to one of those.

Comment: You should have noticed that at the line where you cast to `List<String>`, you get an "unchecked conversion" warning.  This means that you may have lied to the compiler, and as the old saying goes, when you lie to the compiler, it will have its revenge.  A program that compiles with no unchecked or raw warnings is guaranteed that the synthetic casts inserted by the compiler for generics will never fail; that unchecked warning you got (and probably ignored) means "ok, you're on your own, buddy."